# apt update error

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

I keep getting this error whenever I run `sudo apt update`:

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable

deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/overcoder/hexchat/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/overcoder/hexchat/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/overcoder/hexchat/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/overcoder/hexchat/ubuntu xenial main
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
###   TeamViewer DEB repository list

### NOTE: Manual changes to this file
###        - prevent it from being updated by TeamViewer package updates
###        - will be lost after using the 'teamviewer repo' command
###       The original file can be restored with this command:
###       cp /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
###       which has the same effect as 'teamviewer repo default'

### NOTE: It is preferred to use the following commands to edit this file:
###       teamviewer repo                - show current repository configuration
###       teamviewer repo default        - restore default configuration
###       teamviewer repo disable        - disable the repository
###       teamviewer repo main [stable]  - make all TeamViewer packages available (default)
###       teamviewer repo tv13 [stable]  - make TeamViewer 13 packages available
###                             stable     omit preview and beta releases


### Choose stable main to receive updates for TeamViewer 13 and upcoming major releases
### Choose preview main to receive early updates for TeamViewer 13 and to receive major beta releases

### Choose stable tv13 to receive updates for TeamViewer 13
### Choose preview tv13 to receive early updates for TeamViewer 13

deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview main

# deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable tv13
# deb http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview tv13
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial main
# channel for the xenial (16.04) partner channel
# 
#:description:This channel contains the partner software for xenial
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# channel for the xenial (16.04) partner channel
# 
#:description:This channel contains the partner software for xenial
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Comment: so there is no updates for 16.04 and I should update to 16.10?

Comment: No, 16.04 is still supported, it’s Wily (15.10) which isn’t. Are you running 15.10, or 16.04? I’ll write up a proper answer...

Comment: I'm running 16.04

Comment: @GAD3R added an update

Comment: Please check the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: I think this is the one causing the problem deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main universe

Comment: removed it and could update successfully, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re getting that error because Wily (15.10) has reached [the end of its life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and has therefore been archived.

If you’re really running 16.04, you don’t need Wily repositories and you can remove them from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, or whichever file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` refers to Wuly. This will avoid the error you’re getting when running `apt-get update`. Alternatively, you can use `old-releases.ubuntu.com` instead of `archive.ubuntu.com` if you absolutely need the Wily repositories for some reason.

If you’re still running 15.10 however, you should upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: didn't find wily's repositories in /etc/apt/sources, here is the contents of it https://pastebin.com/VUbWcT6J

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the Ubuntu Wily PPA. It seems that it is not supported.
To do that, open *"Software and Updates"* app, then go to *"Other Software"* tab and uncheck the "**ubuntu wily**" PPA, then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```